# サーバーレスアーキテクチャを宣言的に記述したい

Tags: aws

lambda でリクエストを処理する、サーバーレスアーキテクチャがあると思います。lambda の設定自体がある種のプログラム用な形で、その AWS の設定全体がシステムになるのだと理解しています。

これら AWS の機構は、基本的にひとつひとつ設定する形のみで UI ないし API は提供されています。しかし、これをそのまま操作したり、プログラムを実行するスクリプトを書いたりするのは、あまり取り回しがよくありません。

サーバーレスアーキテクチャを、宣言的に記述・管理できるとやりやすいだろうと考えました。

このような仕組み・ツールなどはありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFormationを使ってみてはどうでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

Serverless Archtecture Framework というツールがあります。CloudFormation の拡張のような位置付けです。
https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model

AWS Serverless Application Model (AWS SAM) を使ってサーバーレスアプリケーションを構築する
http://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/aws-serverless-application-model/

その他にも、serverless framework などサードパーティのツールがあります。